# Should I use dependency injection to bring in a class with constants into my Xamarin Forms application or is there a better way?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a class containing constants:

```
namespace Test.AppService
{
    public static class Const
    {
        public const bool Tmr = false;
        public const int Pti = 10;
        ...
```

I was wondering if this would be a good candidate for dependency injection or would it be better to leave it as it is and just add using for Test.AppService into every page? Would appreciate advice on this.

Comment: I fail to see how using DI would improve this in any way.  It's pretty common to directly reference a helper class containing constants.

Comment: Thanks,  the only thing I could think of is perhaps there may be a reason to bring in a different set of constants.  Would that be a possible reason?

Answer (score 1):

Reading your comment about needing to use a different set of constants if that is something you see happening then Dependency injection makes sense. For example if you are using different environments like DEV, QA, Release comes to mind.

You would need to declare an interface with all your public fields. Implement that Interface in different classes with all the possible different scenarios. Then you can register your interface and the class with your desired set of values that you would be able to swap as needed.

For example:

```
public interface IConfiguration
{
    public string ConnectionString {get;} 
}

  public class QaValues : IConfiguration
    {
        public string ConnectionString 
        {   get 
           { 
            return "qaconnection"; 
           }
         }
    }

 public class ReleaseValues : IConfiguration
        {
            public string ConnectionString 
            {   get 
               { 
                return "releaseconnection"; 
               }
             }
        }

DependencyService.Register<IConfiguration,QaValues>();
```